# Eclipse: Custom warnings (Rhino String params)

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, rhino

Is there a way to define a custom warning in Eclipse?  How?

#### My motivation

I have a Large Number of classes that are exposed as JavaScript objects via Mozilla Rhino.  I've run across a couple bugs like this:

```
public void jsFunction_foo(String bar) {
  if (bar != null) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

The Bug: A String parameter in a `jsFunction_` IS NEVER NULL.  If the JavaScript calls `foo(null)`, the parameter that arrives is `"null"`, not `null`.  HUGE difference.

The solution is to declare the parameter as `Scriptable`, and then convert it if present:

```
public void jsFunction_foo(Scriptable bar) {
  if (bar != null) {
    String barStr = convertToString(bar);
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

So anyway.  We have 50+ classes we expose in JavaScript.  Rather than schlepping through them all by hand, I'd like to automate the process.  Something like:

```
if (function.name.indexOf("jsFunction_") == 0 &&
    function.paramTypes.contains(String.class) &&
    stringParamComparedToNull(function))
  addWarning(function.lineNum, "It doesn't work like that!");
```

Ideally this custom warning would be shared across my team (or even with the Mozilla Rhino project itself) so other folks won't keep making the same mistakes.

A way to crash Eclipse for people that compare to "null" would be good too.  Grr.

Comment: Funny Story:  Rhino Doesn't Do That.  If you list a parameter as a String and pass `null`, you get a `null`.  Our internal "smart" type conversion explicitly calls `Context.toString`.  Oops.  Still, a good question.  Thank you Andrey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) to define a [custom rule using variant of XPath](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/xpathruletutorial.html) over the Java code. PMD also has [Eclipse plugin](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/eclipse/).